# How to talk about a random variable which only exists on an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have some probability space, and some event $A$ which has probability close to, but not equal to $1$.  Suppose that on this event, we can construct a random variable $X$.  (For example, constructing a path in a rectangle between points in a point process, conditioned on the event $A$ that there are any points in the rectangle)

How do I talk about the random variable $X$, if I want to work with it?  Do I keep saying things like, "On the event $A$, $X \leq Y$"?

Or do I say "$X \mathbb{1}_A \leq Y\mathbb{1}_A$"?

Do these statements even make sense if $X$ doesn't exist on the whole probability space?

Sorry if this question isn't clear, I can try to clarify.

Comment: The definition of a random variable is that it is a measurable function, so in particular it must be a function.  That means you have to define it on the whole space.

Comment: Technically you already has a binary random variable $Z$ which is $1_A$. Now you have to define your $X$ as $f(Z)$.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner, if I wanted $X$ to be, for example, a certain path between points in a rectangle of a point process, and $A$ is the event that there are points in the rectangle, how could I write $X$ as $f(\mathbb{1}_A)$?  $\mathbb{1}_A$ only takes the values $0$ and $1$, and doesn't give information as to where the points are in $A$ or anything like that.

Comment: This is weird. Random variable should be a mapping from some $\sigma$ algebra of events to some space. You $X$ is not well defined, since $X$ might be different even in the case of event $A$. You have to or redefine the space of events or redefine your $X$.  BTW what does it mean $X\le Y$. Is $X$ the length of the path?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner "Random variable should be a mapping from some σ algebra of events to some space" Actually a random variable is a mapping defined on a space endowed with some σ-algebra of events, not a mapping defined on some σ-algebra.

Comment: Here's an example that might clear up what I'm asking:  Suppose I would like to lower bound the maximal action of a path in some random environment.  Take nearest neighbor lazy paths, and say the action is the sum of the variables the path moves through.  Suppose that with probability close to 1, there exist a "good site", and we can construct a path which moves to that site and stays there.  On the event that this site exists, I can bound the maximal path by the action of this path I've constructed.  However, I can only construct this path on this sub-event.  How do I write this?

Comment: Have your new random variable be whatever you want on the nice set and be equal to the thing you are trying to bound off of it. That way it's defined everywhere and serves as a lower bound everywhere.